# Rails 4 : Exception Site(#70058148983820) expected, got String(#8388700)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, exception

I have a form with a selectbox which allow to select differents values. When I want to save the form I have an exception :

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch at xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Site(#70058148983820) expected, got String(#8388700)
```

## Here is the form which generate the select box

```
col-md-9
  .input-group.btn-group
    %span.input-group-addon
    =t('activerecord.attributes.user.volunteer_wishes_sites')
    = f.collection_select :wishes_sites, @sites, :id, :name, {:selected => @user.wishes_sites.map(&:id)}, {:multiple => true, :class=>"sites_multiselect"}
```

## In my controller I have

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(
    :wishes_sites =>[],
  )
end
```

## The model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ....
  has_and_belongs_to_many :wishes_sites, :class_name => "Site", :join_table => :wishes_sites
end
```

## here is the line which produces the bug

```
if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
```

## Here are the migration

```
create_table :sites, force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.text     "address"
  t.text     "description"
end

create_table :wishes_sites, id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.integer "site_id"
end
```

**Here is the log before the exception:**

```
Processing by Backoffice::UsersController#update_volunteer as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=", "user"=>{"volunteer_driving_b"=>"1", "volunteer_driving_a"=>"1", "volunteer_driving_d"=>"1", "volunteer_driving_license_number"=>"123456", "volunteer_owns_car"=>"1", "volunteer_owns_motorcycle"=>"1", "volunteer_owns_tramway_card"=>"1", "volunteer_owns_bicycle"=>"1", "spoken_languages"=>["", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "36"], "volunteer_aid_certificate"=>"bouche à bouche", "wishes_sites"=>["", "1", "2"], "wishes_position_categories"=>["", "1"], "sports_association"=>"true", "sports_association_comment"=>"Les petit chanteurs à la croix", "experienced"=>"true", "experienced_comment"=>"1999 Ramasseur de papiers", "kept_tshirt"=>"true", "volunteer_remark"=>"Aucun car je suis ok sur tout", "accept_volunteer_list"=>"0", "accept_volunteer_rules"=>"1", "volunteer_checked"=>"0", "compensation"=>"empty2", "volunteer_comment"=>""}, "spoken_languages_levels"=>{"2"=>"basic", "3"=>"intermediate", "4"=>"fluent", "5"=>"fluent", "6"=>"intermediate", "36"=>"basic"}, "availability"=>["49", "53", "57", "49", "53", "57"], "button"=>"", "id"=>"15429", "locale"=>"fr"}

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 434ms
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch - Site(#70057393394640) expected, got String(#8388700):
```

Comment: Could you show logs before the error? Esp. the params sent to the server.

Comment: Question edited with log

Answer (score 0):

Can you show how do you define `@sites` variable? Check if the string value isn't assigned to it instead of a collection of Sites.

Comment: I'm not using @sites in this module.

Comment: You use it in your `f.collection_select` statement. It feels like the attributes are passed in a wrong format or the @sites variable is not really what `collection_select` expects. See [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) for some examples.